# R scale function with character variable

Tags: r, dataframe, cluster-analysis, scale

I'm relatively new to R - I'm having challenges to figure out how to scale a dataset that contains a character variable.

However I when I try to use the scale function to create a dataframe, I'm getting an error:

```
 df<-scale(USArrests)
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Is there a way to create a dataframe with a character variable to later use it in a cluster analysis?

```
km.res<-kmeans(df,4,nstart=10)
```

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: (And I say that after having tried `scale(USArrests)` on the data from the `datasets` package, and I don't get an error. Perhaps something you may have done previously to "clean" or "groom" `USArrests` corrupted something within it. If you brought the row names in as a column, then perhaps `scale(USArrests[,-1])`?)

Comment: I realize my first comment (about the image) was perhaps a little premature/harsh, since `USArrests` is from the `datasets` package.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans , I'll  keep that in mind going. I've removed the image.

Ohhh okay cool, thanks yeah I see it was when actually modified the data. Replacing the dataset with the original file worked 100%.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`?scale()` says `scale` is desgined to center columns of numeric matrices, see the help entry for further details.
However, `df <- USArrests` is sufficient to store the required in-built dataset as object `df` (see environment), if you have to name it df.
Compare the following:

```
df <- USArrests
# compare
head(df, n=5)
# to 
df1 <- scale(df)
head(df1, n=5)
```

As you can see, all numeric columns are now scaled while the row ids, Alabama, ..., Wyoming, of course, do not change. Btw, to check the class of all variables you can use `lapply(df, class)`.

I think you shouldn't have problems to then call `km.res <- kmeans(df1,4,nstart=10)`. To inspect the object type `km.res`.

To be honest, I think previous to running `kmeans()` you should again have a look on the help page (e.g. `help(kmeans)`) to get in touch with the arguments `clusters`, `iter`, ...
Further, I think it would be a good idea to investigate why or why not to center the data in previous step. In any case, it is possible to run `kmeans()` with centered (df1) and uncentered (df) data. Why one of those alternatives is more appropriate is of major importance.

EDIT: It is recommended to set a seed (e.g. `set.seed(09102021)`) before running the algorithm. By doing so you ensure the reproducibility of results.